# JavaScript alternative to MediaWiki's PHP footnote mechanism

Tags: javascript, html, function, templates, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki 1.32.0 Right-To-Left (RTL;Hebrew) website and I desire to have this website free of external extensions; that is; without extensions that aren't shipped with the core --- thus also without [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) used to create footnotes by PHP in RTL MediaWiki sites.
Hence, I desire an alternative approach with JavaScript.

Trying to achieve this I created two templates:

**1)**: `template:footnote`:

```
<p>
    <span class="footnote"><sup></sup></span>
</p>
```

**2)**: `template:footnotes_list`:

```
<ol id="footnotes_list">
</ol>
```

Text of a footnote added in template call (as `{{footnote|FOOTNOTE_TEXT}}`) should appear in the above `<sup></sup>` and then be transported into the `<ol></ol>` which should by itself appear in `{{footnotes_list}}`:

```
const list = document.querySelector("#footnotes_list");
document.querySelectorAll(".footnote>sup").forEach((footnote, i) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.append(...footnote.childNodes);
    list.appendChild(li);
    footnote.textContent = i+1;
});
```

How could I ensure that text added inside **footnote** template call will appear in `<sup></sup>`?

Comment: FWIW the Cite extension [is shipped with core](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Bundled_extensions_and_skins).

Comment: @Tgr my personal pain is that Scribunto isn't while it is needed to property format references in RTL wikis (as far as I know and I might be wrong).

Comment: The template snippets you provide do not have anything RTL-specific in them, though. Also, AFAIK the big RTL wikis do use Cite without problems (see e.g. the citations [here](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B1%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A9).)

Comment: @Tgr the problem has to do with processing the vertical-bar (`|`) and the content after it; if I'm not wrong, Hebrew Wikipedia uses Scribunto to allow this "passing of an argument" after vertical bar in Hebrew, without getting empty content as I got here, please see also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048049/add-textcontent-to-html-via-mediawiki-template