# Add textContent to HTML via MediaWiki template

Tags: html, templates, syntax, output, mediawiki

I have created a MediaWiki template named by the Hebrew letter **א** (`template:א`). Its content is:

```
<code></code>
```

I call it by `{{א|SOME_textContent}}`.

### Desired state

I desire to show a **single-line code** iside regular text, for example:

> הסימן הזה `=` הינו סימן שוויון

### My problem

My problem is that after I save a page with the above template call, I get an empty `<code>` tag content ().

### My question

Why do I get empty `<code>` tag content (), instead getting `SOME_textContent` (the input I gave in call after the vertical bar (`|`))?

### Update - I tried this but didn't get desired state

Template page code:

```
<code>{{{1}}}</code>
```

Template page output:

`{{{1}}}`

Article page code:

```
{{א|=}}
```

Article page output:

`{{{1}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, everything inside `code` tag will not be parsed, so your parameter is interpreted as string.

Instead of using html markup `<code>`, use parser function `#tag` like so:

{{#tag:code | { { phone code area: 970}, { phone code area: 961}, { phone code area: 98} } }}

So your template will look like:

```
 <includeonly>{{#tag:code| {{{1}}} }}</includeonly>
```

Comment: Thank you IRA1777, sadly I share that it didn't work... Please see my updated question.

Comment: Your problem is the '**=**' character in the input text, it makes the parser believe that everything left of **=** is a parameter name, and right is the assigned value. Just like if you had {{{הינו סימן שוויון}}} as named parameter. Take my code for template, and call it like {{A|1= SOME_textContent}}.

Comment: Which is by the way what Tgr told you

Answer (score 0):

A template won't magically insert its parameters unless you tell it. The correct template content would be

```
<code>{{{1}}}</code>
```

Comment: `{{א|=}}` passes a single parameter, the name of which is the empty string (unlike `{{א|foo}}` or `{{א|1=}}`, both of which pass a parameter named `1`). See [the manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Parameters) for more info. It might be easier if you explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: (Note that the last example has the form `{{x|1=}}`, not `{{1|x=}}` which is how the browsers display it due to Unicode LTR character rendering rules. Noted [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387251/rtl-characters-in-code-snippets).)